# How to retrieve matched resources of a request in a ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, jax-rs

I am working on a WebService using JAX-RS/Jersey.

I've set up a *ContainerRequestFilter* whose purpose is to authenticate the user. I only need to protect some of the paths with authentication, the rest can be available to everyone.

I want to retrieve matchedResources / matchedResults via ExtendedUriInfo in my ContainerRequestFilter so that I can check if the path should be protected or not. Is there a way to create a filter which is invoked after ExtendedUriInfo is populated, but before the matched resource class and method is invoked?

Comment: Sounds like you're reinventing a bit of Java EE!  If you don't have an EJB sitting behind your web-service, consider adding one.  You'll be able to annotate with roles as you please.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Richard. I haven't looked in to Roles all that much yet, but I had the impression Roles worked only with an *auth-method* configured. I have a *login* method, and after the user logs in he/she communicates with the WebService using an accessToken + userId pair.

Comment: Admittedly my experience with authentication via web-services is weak. I do know that via the servlet interface there is an API available to log a user in - side stepping the auth-method. In short, servlets can "code their own" authentication method. I'd always assumed there was such for web-services as well.

Comment: Since you're using a filter, that mechanism should be available to you: see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a more general answer (for instance if you're using another jax-rs implementation like CXF):

Just add the following in your filter class as an instance variable:

> @Context
>
> ResourceInfo info;
>
> "javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo is a new JAX-RS context which can
>   be injected into filters and interceptors and **checked which resource
>   class and method are about to be invoked.**"

(source : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAX-RS+Basics#JAX-RSBasics-ResourceInfo)

[Original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525185/how-to-get-target-resource-from-containerrequestfilter-in-apache-cxf/20519922#20519922)

Answer (score 5):

Found a way to do it with *ContainerRequestFilter*:

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    UriRoutingContext routingContext = (UriRoutingContext) requestContext.getUriInfo();
    ResourceMethodInvoker invoker = (ResourceMethodInvoker) routingContext.getInflector();
    Class<?> className = invoker.getResourceClass();
    Method methodName = invoker.getResourceMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure it out.

The approach I have found to work is to abandon doing this in the *ContainerRequestFilter* and create a *ResourceFilterFactory* instead. In the *ResourceFilterFactory* I can use

```
AbstractMethod.isAnnotationPresent(clazz)
```

to determine if my custom annotation is present. If my annotation is present, I can then return a list containing my *AuthenticationContainerRequestFilter*.

Another tip for anyone reading this answer is that injection in the ContainerRequestFilter will not work when using the *ResourceFilterFactory* approach. What I did was to do any injection in the *ResourceFilterFactory* and then pass the injected objects to the *ContainerRequestFilter* via its constructor.