# How to get Target Resource from ContainerRequestFilter in Apache CXF

Tags: java, spring, rest, cxf, jax-rs

I am creating a RESTful web service using Apache CXF.
I want to do an authentication of requests to resources that are annotated with @Authenticate. For this I intend to write a post matching ContainerRequestFilter and validate the request and do ContainerRequestContext.abortWith(javax.ws.rs.core.Response) if the authentication failed. However I only want to do authentication for resources that are annotated with @Authenticate.

The problem is I can't find out how to get access to the matched resource. I know I can use CXF interceptors to do it, but I want to stick with what JAX-RS 2.0 provides.
I saw in another post that you can use the below in Rest-easy

```
ResourceMethodInvoker methodInvoker = (ResourceMethodInvoker) 
            requestContext.getProperty("org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker");
Method method = methodInvoker.getMethod();
```

Can a similar approach be done in CXF?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following in your filter class as an instance variable:

> @Context
>
> ResourceInfo info;
>
> "javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo is a new JAX-RS context which can
>   be injected into filters and interceptors and **checked which resource
>   class and method are about to be invoked.**"

(source : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAX-RS+Basics#JAX-RSBasics-ResourceInfo)